# Update Python 2.7 datetime type in python 3.6 datetime object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-3.6, python-datetime

I am working on make python 2.7 code compatible for python 3.6.

Code is working fine in python 2.7 but i am getting datetime issue  in python 3.6 :

```
 def insert_event(self, subject_event):
        for x in range (0,self.event_count):
            if self.events[x].time <= subject_event.time:


TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

When i did debug the code i got this:

In python 3.6 :

```
(Pdb) print (subject_event)
<event.Event object at 0x7f89b7cdb908>
(Pdb) print (subject_event.time)
2018-01-01 06:05:00
(Pdb) self.events
[<event.Event object at 0x7f89b7cd1da0>, <event.Event object at 0x7f89b7cd1828>]
(Pdb) self.events[0]
<event.Event object at 0x7f89b7cd1da0>
(Pdb) self.events[0].time
<class 'datetime.datetime'>



(Pdb) self.events[x]
<event.Event object at 0x7ffb339a31d0>
(Pdb) type(self.events[x])
<class 'event.Event'>
(Pdb) self.events[x].time
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
(Pdb) type(self.events[x].time)
<class 'type'>

(Pdb) self.events[x].__dict__
{'time': <class 'datetime.datetime'>, 'id': 'bcdfd404-67e9-4ef3-a699-8afde902685e', 'constraint': None, 'constraint_time': <class 'datetime.time'>, 'action': 'ShiftStart', 'cust_in_car': 0, 'previous': None, 'neo_id': 1340, 'user': None, 'place': None, 'resource': None, 'shift': None, 'linked': None, 'epoch': 1514775600000, '_driver': <neo4j.v1.direct.DirectDriver object at 0x7ffb339a3390>}
(Pdb) self.events[x].time.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__hash__': <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__str__': <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__add__': <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__radd__': <slot wrapper '__radd__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__sub__': <slot wrapper '__sub__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__rsub__': <slot wrapper '__rsub__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x9f7500>, 'now': <method 'now' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utcnow': <method 'utcnow' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'fromtimestamp': <method 'fromtimestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utcfromtimestamp': <method 'utcfromtimestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'strptime': <method 'strptime' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'combine': <method 'combine' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'date': <method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'time': <method 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'timetz': <method 'timetz' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'ctime': <method 'ctime' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'timetuple': <method 'timetuple' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'timestamp': <method 'timestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utctimetuple': <method 'utctimetuple' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'isoformat': <method 'isoformat' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utcoffset': <method 'utcoffset' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'tzname': <method 'tzname' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'dst': <method 'dst' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'replace': <method 'replace' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'astimezone': <method 'astimezone' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__reduce_ex__': <method '__reduce_ex__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__reduce__': <method '__reduce__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'hour': <attribute 'hour' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'minute': <attribute 'minute' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'second': <attribute 'second' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'microsecond': <attribute 'microsecond' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'tzinfo': <attribute 'tzinfo' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'fold': <attribute 'fold' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__doc__': 'datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])\n\nThe year, month and day arguments are required. tzinfo may be None, or an\ninstance of a tzinfo subclass. The remaining arguments may be ints.\n', 'min': datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'max': datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 'resolution': datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 1)})
```

In python 2.7 :

```
(Pdb) self.events[x]
<event.Event object at 0x7fce0b43c590>
(Pdb) type(self.events[x])
<class 'event.Event'>
(Pdb) self.events[x].time
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
(Pdb) type(self.events[x].time)
<type 'type'>

(Pdb) self.events[x].__dict__
{'resource': None, 'constraint_time': <type 'datetime.time'>, 'constraint': None, 'shift': None, '_driver': <neo4j.v1.direct.DirectDriver object at 0x7fce0b43c910>, 'cust_in_car': 0, 'linked': None, 'epoch': 1514775600000, 'place': None, 'user': None, 'time': <type 'datetime.datetime'>, 'action': 'ShiftStart', 'neo_id': 2339, 'id': 'e828acca-5d32-42e1-967d-c044c775ae47', 'previous': None}
(Pdb) self.events[x].time.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__str__': <slot wrapper '__str__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__getattribute__': <slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__radd__': <slot wrapper '__radd__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utctimetuple': <method 'utctimetuple' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'second': <attribute 'second' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utcnow': <method 'utcnow' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__lt__': <slot wrapper '__lt__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__sub__': <slot wrapper '__sub__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__new__': <built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x939c20>, 'min': datetime.datetime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'dst': <method 'dst' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'astimezone': <method 'astimezone' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'strptime': <method 'strptime' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utcfromtimestamp': <method 'utcfromtimestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'combine': <method 'combine' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'timetuple': <method 'timetuple' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'max': datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999999), 'tzinfo': <attribute 'tzinfo' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__doc__': 'datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])\n\nThe year, month and day arguments are required. tzinfo may be None, or an\ninstance of a tzinfo subclass. The remaining arguments may be ints or longs.\n', 'tzname': <method 'tzname' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'isoformat': <method 'isoformat' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__ne__': <slot wrapper '__ne__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__reduce__': <method '__reduce__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'replace': <method 'replace' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'utcoffset': <method 'utcoffset' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'microsecond': <attribute 'microsecond' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__add__': <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__gt__': <slot wrapper '__gt__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'date': <method 'date' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'now': <method 'now' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__eq__': <slot wrapper '__eq__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'minute': <attribute 'minute' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'ctime': <method 'ctime' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'hour': <attribute 'hour' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'fromtimestamp': <method 'fromtimestamp' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__le__': <slot wrapper '__le__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__repr__': <slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'time': <method 'time' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__hash__': <slot wrapper '__hash__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, '__rsub__': <slot wrapper '__rsub__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'timetz': <method 'timetz' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>, 'resolution': datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 1), '__ge__': <slot wrapper '__ge__' of 'datetime.datetime' objects>})
```

Any changes in datetime in python 3.6 ?

Comment: Your first value in comparison is not a `DateTime` instance but the `DateTime` class.

Comment: try this in python2.7 and python3: `import datetime; type(datetime.datetime.now()) <= datetime.datetime.now()` you will get `False` in python2.7 and unorderable type error in python3. my guess is the code was never working in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the `TypeError` is that in Python 3 objects of different types are **not comparable** (with some exceptions, such as numeric types). In Python 2 comparing objects of different types is legal.

Check [What's new in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) for more details.

BTW, you most likely want to compare two `datetime` *instances*, not the class and an instance.

Comment: in python 2.7 :from datetime import datetime ; start_date = datetime , type of start_date is type.
in python 3.6 : from datetime import datetime; start_date = datetime , type of start_date is class.

Comment: start_date <=  datetime.now(), will get true/false in python 2.7 and in python 3.6 , start_time <=  datetime.now() , will get `typeerror`